# Climbing Insurance

Tags: climbing, rock-climbing

I think I should've donde this ages ago, but, well... better late than never.

Could you recommend a good insurance that covers climbing? It could be a travel insurance or a medical insurance. I'm not base anywhere at the moment, I was based in Australia, I'm a mexican citizen and will eventually relocate to the US, so maybe something that is based on any of those countries could be an option, but it would be important for it to cover any other country so I don't have to keep looking for options every time I switch.

I found a few options on google, but nothing appropriate after I read the small print. Plus  I would like to hear what's working for you guys.

Thanks

Comment: Shopping recommendations are not a good fit for SE as the answers will change over time and are in any case very subjective. The [FAQ] explains this.

Comment: As @RoryAlsop said, this isn't the best fit for our site. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Here in France, as you subscribe to the FFM (something like Mountain French Association), understand you pay for a licence, in this licence is included an obligatory minimum insurance, that you can extend if you wish.
I think that you should first look for a club and then ask them for insurance.
But of course, the very first insurance is yourself, always take care of yourse

Comment: Well put, the first insurance (and safety line) is yourself!

Answer (score 0):

Try Atlas travel insurance from HCC MIS: http://www.hccmis.com/

It only excludes professional sports and competitions (if not speaking of death payments). All non-professional sport is included in standard price.

Never had any accidents with it, though.